# How to render fire in cycles?

Tags: smoke-simulation

I don't understand how smoke is supposed to work in Blender 2.8 (Cycles rendering). No matter what I do, I cannot get a render of smoke. This is extremely weird, since the smoke renders perfectly fine in the 3D viewport:
[image]

I scoured the net and found this node setup that was supposed to fix the issue, but it doesn't actually do anything:

[image]

I followed the steps [from this tutorial](https://youtu.be/u-zK7Bu8cAI):

1. Add object
2. In object mode, Object -> Quick Effects -> Quick Smoke

And immediately, the effect will work in the 3D viewport in all modes, but it will never render. Please help me, I've been trying to solve this for 3 hours and nothing helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried making a smoke scene to see if I could answer this, and I had the same problem, I fixed it by baking the smoke simulation.  (go to the physics tab of the domain cube and under **cache** press **bake**.

I hope that fixes the problem.

As a side note, for an easier smoke and fire material, you can use the *Principled Volume BSDF*.  This can be used for smoke and fire.

Here's a picture of the node set up and the result.[image]

The two settings you can change to change the look of the smoke is **color** and **density**.  I hope this is helpful to you. :)

Comment: +1 for recreating the problem from scratch

Comment: hot damn, it works ! Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad i could help. :) could you mark it as accepted so people will know it has been answered?  (plus it gives me extra reputation points, which are useful for bounties)  :)