# How do I render fire + smoke?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation, fire

I am trying to render a simple rocket ship animation. I have used the advice from [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/155848/how-to-render-fire-in-cycles?newreg=723140d97f924075bac20b36aa6edff3), but it only displays the fire & smoke in the solid mode of viewport shading. In material preview and render preview modes, it displays the smoke but not the fire. Is there anything that the aforementioned question doesn't include that might help? I'm using the Cycles render engine, by the way.

[image: solid mode rocket]
[image: render preview rocket]
[image: flame+smoke source settings]
[image: flame+smoke domain settings]

Comment: I'm so sorry for how ridiculously tall this thing is.